# have an error creating a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I installed to database and got the following error:

> Don't created: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near `timestamp`(10), `KEY` vid (vid)' at line 4

As you see I had errors to start with and used (As recommended here) the "`" , but now I am stuck with this latest error on same table.

Comment: Show the SQL command

Comment: mysql != sql-server

Comment: $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$ine.C_MYSQL_VOTE_IPS." (
  vid smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ip int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0',
  `time` `timestamp`(10),
  `KEY` vid (vid)";

Answer (score 0):

MySQL retrieves and displays `TIMESTAMP` values in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format
and you have used `timestamp(10)`, which is invalid

Also `TIME` is reserved word, so its recommended to use some other name for table column.

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE `pravion` (
  `vid` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`)
);
```

Comment: Ok, so I can take out (10) from the table query?

Comment: Yes, read mysql data type article. here 10 is used for field length which is not applicable for date OR datetime or few more data type field

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$ine.C_MYSQL_VOTE_IPS." ( vid smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ip int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0', time timestamp(10), KEY vid (vid)";

**QUERY**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE `C_MYSQL_VOTE_IPS` (
  `vid` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vid`)
);
```

> Don't use reserved words and if you are using reserved words try to use these words within backtick (`)

Ref: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)